# Swap SVG onTouchStart in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have SVGs that are acting as buttons for an app. There is a normal and a pressed version of these SVGs. onTouchStart, the pressed SVG should be displayed, onTouchEnd, the SVG goes back to normal. What is a good way to handle this sort of situation in React?

This was my approach, but I find the onTouchStart switches the button as expected, but onTouchEnd does not seem to re-render.

```
function HomeButton(props: ButtonProps) {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  
  function handleTouchStart() {
    setPressed(true)
  }

  function handleTouchEnd() {
    setPressed(false)
  }

  return <button onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}>{pressed ? <SVGPressed /> : <SVGNormal />}</button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. After digging around, I found a response to a similar problem that stated a possible race condition between the page rerender and the onTouchEnd event.

I set the SVG node that changes between pressed and normal states, and set that to a variable that is changed with the onTouchStart and onTouchEnd events. Everything seems to be working beautifully now.